# How to set the markers icon?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to cluster my markers on the GoogleMaps map on my Android device. therefore, I tried [this](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity.java) example:

```
public class GoogleMapClusterItem implements ClusterItem {
public final String name;

public final int profilePhoto; // resource id

public final LatLng mPosition;

public MapClusterItem(double lat, double lng, String name, int pictureResource) {
    this.name = name;
    profilePhoto = pictureResource;
    mPosition = new LatLng(lat, lng);
}

@Override
public LatLng getPosition() {
    return mPosition;
}
}
```

And then I call in the Main Activity:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        double offset = i / 60d;
        lat = lat + offset;
        lng = lng + offset;
        MapClusterItem offsetItem = new MapClusterItem(lat, lng, "Casa Mia", R.drawable.ic_casa);

        mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
    }
```

I would like to replace a markers icon with an individial png picture. But there is always the red standard marker symbol.

**Where should I call the drawMarker Method then?**

As you can see, these are not Marker objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
    private void drawMarker(LatLng point, int drawable)
    {
       MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
       markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(drawable));
       markerOptions.position(point);
       googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
```

You can use the above method to draw markers where param `drawable` is the drawable resource id (image) and point is LatLng where the marker has to be drawn.